# How to exclude input folder from find results

Tags: bash, find

I have executed this command to find entries with the current folder.

```
find . -maxdepth 1
```

#### Expected result

```
./main.c
./g2074048
./main
./g2092405
./Tests
```

#### Output

```
.
./main.c
./g2074048
./main
./g2092405
./Tests
```

How to have an output that does not include the current directory ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.
I only had to add `-mindepth 1`

#### Correct command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1
```